# Get color of word under cursor

Tags: vim, colors

How do i get the color of the word under the cursor?

Working on making my own color schemes and trying to poach others colors without having to look at the source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "fg")
```

- `"fg"`  foreground color (GUI: color name used to set the color, cterm: color number as a string, term: empty string),
- `"bg"` background color (as with "fg").

Read more

- [`:help synIDattr()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#synIDattr%28%29)